# Segmentation fault when running C program for integer multiplication with insufficient arguments

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, multiplication

I am working on a C program that is supposed to multiply two integers and print the result of the multiplication. If the program does not receive exactly 2 arguments, it should print "Error" and return 1.

I compiled the program with the following command:

`gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 3-mul.c -o mul`

When I run the program with `./mul int1 int2` or `./mul int1 int2 int3`, it outputs the correct result. However, when I run it with just `./mul`, it produces a segmentation fault, rather than printing "Error" as I expect.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv)
{
  int x = atoi(argv[1])
  int y = atoi(argv[2])

if (argc == 3)
   {
       printf("%d\n", x * y);
   }
else
   { 
       printf("Error\n");
       return 1;
    }

return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I modify my code to produce the expected output when called with insufficient arguments?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `if (argc == 3)` Do that check **before** accessing the `argv` values as is done the two lines above that.

Comment: *int x = atoi(argv[1]);*  and *int y = atoi(argv[2]);* has missing semicolon ;

Comment: `**argv` or `*argv[]` is the correct way of getting arguments to the main function.

Comment: Raise the warning level to the maximum, and correct your code until you have no warnings.

Comment: Seg fault? It doesn't even compile for 4 warnings and 2 errors (MSVC). Please copy/paste the exact code.

Comment: @kaylum I did the check before accessing argv as you suggested and it has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // char* argv[] here
{
  if (argc != 3)                // test argc *before* dereferencing argv[1] and argv[2]
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int x = atoi(argv[1]);
  int y = atoi(argv[2]);
  printf("%d\n", x * y);  
  return 0;
}
```

You are dereferencing `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` **before** testing if `argc` is 3. Instructions are executed sequencially. If you execute your program without arguments on the command line, `argc` will be 1 and `argv[1]` is out of bounds hence the seg fault.

Moreover the signature of `main` is wrong, it should be `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. The second argument of `main` is an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: Or better yet: `int x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);`. `atoi` should never be used.